# Pandas: Creation of a new DataFrame if with values contained in two others

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas Dataframes and would like to create a new DataFrame.
The DataFrames look like this:

```
      DataFrame 1                                             DataFrame 2

 |Datetime               |Val k    |Val m   |        |Datetime               |Val x| 
 |-----------------------|---------|--------|        |-----------------------|-----|
0|2020-12-16 01:18:10.267|k=13.0703|m=0.6600|       0|2020-12-16 01:18:10.267|2    |
1|2020-12-24 11:00:34.123|k=10.6973|m=0.3200|  and  1|2021-01-29 22:18:00.152|2    |
2|2021-01-29 22:18:00.152|k=9.7890 |m=0.6300|       2|2021-01-30 23:12:47.260|2    |
3|2021-03-19 12:12:47.260|k=9.8476 |m=0.3300|       3|2021-02-31 18:12:50.000|2    |
.|          .            |    .    |    .   |       .|          .            |.    |
.|          .            |    .    |    .   |       .|          .            |.    |
.|          .            |    .    |    .   |       .|          .            |.    |
```

Now I want to get a new DataFrame with the rows and columns of DataFrame 1, but only if the datetime is also contained in DataFrame 2:
(Same datetimes do not have the same indices)

```
 |Datetime               |Val k    |Val m   |
 |-----------------------|---------|--------|
0|2020-12-16 01:18:10.267|k=13.0703|m=0.6600|
1|2021-01-29 22:18:00.152|k=9.7890 |m=0.6300|
.|          .            |    .    |    .   | 
.|          .            |    .    |    .   |     
.|          .            |    .    |    .   |
```

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: so you want to keep the rows of df1 that have their datetime in df2? that's it?. Also split the tables into separate rows in your question, otherwise we can't copy paste to reproduce

Comment: seems he basically wants his first dataframe filtered to only have dates present in the dataframe 2

Comment: `df1.loc[df1['Datetime'].isin(df2['Datetime'])]` should do it

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options to do this kind of tasks:

- slice the first table `df1` based on the second table `df2` (so you basically create a boolean vector)
- [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both tables

Let us assume that we have two tables: `df1`

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 3 | 30 |
| 3 | 4 | 40 |
| 4 | 5 | 50 |

and `df2`

|  | A | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 33 |
| 1 | 5 | 55 |

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 5], 'C': [33, 55]})


# option 1: slicing
lg = df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])
print(df1[lg])
# option 2: merge
print(df1.merge(df2))
```

Output option 1: **slicing**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 5 | 50 |

Output option 2: **merge**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 30 | 33 |
| 1 | 5 | 50 | 55 |

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dataframe.join(df)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,'a'),(2,'a')], columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(1,'a'),(3,'b')], columns=['a','c'])
l = len(df1.columns)
df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index('a'), on='a', how='inner').iloc[:,:l]

df3
    a   b
0   1   a
```